# Flexbox : fill space but not last if odd

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to realize this with flexbox:

[image: Desired outcome]

Currently, I encapsulate in groups of inputs, where I apply display flex. I'd like if the last element is odd (if I have 3, 5... inputs) that the last one is not filling the whole space and just get the size of the other ones (that are filling the space).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

In my current code, I did to input groups (the first one with the 3 first, then another one for password):

```html
<div class="inputsGroup">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="firstname">Prénom</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Jean" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="lastname">Nom</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Dupont" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="email">Adresse e-mail</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="example@domaine.com" name="email">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputsGroup">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <p class="body-2 info">Votre mot de passe doit contenir au minimum 8 caractères contenant lettres, chiffres et caractères spéciaux.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="passwordConfirmation">Confirmation du mot de passe</label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordConfirmation">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="loginButtons">
  <button class="btn btn-primary loginSubmit">Connexion</button>
  <button class="btn btn-tertiary passwordReset">Mot de passe oublié</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try using `display: grid` rather than `display: flex` so that it's the parent element controlling the size of the inputs

Comment: We need to see your CSS, without the styling we don't know what it actually looks like for you

Comment: Currently the CSS was only a basic display flex because I'm not really familiar with the sizing properties for flex. But I tried what @auTiStiCWizArD was saying and grid seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the comments, using display: grid is more appropriate.

This is what I've done :

```css
.inputsGroup{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 24px;
```

This creates a grid with 2 columns that are both taking the available space (they balance each other). And then, the third element is moved to a new line.